# Number Input value format

Tags: html, angular, input

I have two inputs, the first called before, and second called after
when i introduce a value in `before` the `after` value will be

> before / 1000

witch it means 3 decimals or more sometimes
How should i display the `after` input value with 2 decimals only? without changing its decimal value and precicision
Is there any #HTML #JS or #Angular tip
I tried to use pipes, but they aren't allowed in ngModel directives

```
<ion-label for="ristourneAmount">Source: </ion-label>
<ion-input 
  type="number"
  step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="before" 
  (change)="onChange()">
</ion-input>
<ion-label for="ristourneAmount">Destination: </ion-label>
<ion-input 
  type="number"
  step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="after">
</ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ion-input 
  type="number"
  step="0.01"(change)="setTwoNumberDecimal($event)"
  (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event"
  [[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
  [ngModel]="after">
  </ion-input>
```

Rather than using two way binding you can use single way binding and tap on the events of blur and change on the event declare the function in angular which should be doing the following

```
setTwoNumberDecimal(event:any){
 let value=event.value;
 event.value=value.toFixed(2);
}
```